# Unity : Register and resolve class that implements generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I am trying to use generics to subscribe handlers to different events. I have the following interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IEvent { }

public class CompletedEvent : IEvent { }

public interface IHandle<T> where T: IEvent { }

public class CompletedHandler : IHandle<CompletedEvent>  
{     
    public void Handle(CompletedEvent args)
    {  
        args.Completed.Path = "\...";
    }
}
```

And I would like to resolve handler like this :

```
Container.ResolveAll<IHandle<T>>();
```

I have tried several approaches to register the above class in Unity but I did not succeed. Among which were

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(IHandle<CompletedEvent>), typeof(CompletedHandler));
```

and

```
Container.RegisterType<IHandle<CompletedEvent>, CompletedHandler>();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem and I am in a hurry to share about it and a solution, if some one is going the same erroneous steps I did. It turned out that my registration was okay, but the problem was in the handler factory where I violated the Liskov substitution principle. Here is the code.

```
 public interface IEventFactory
 {
    IEvent Create(...);
 }

 public class CompletedEventFactory : IEventFactory
 {
    ...

    public IEvent Create(...)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<CompletedEvent>(new ParameterOverride(...));
    }

}

public class Service
{
    ...

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var completedEvent = _eventFactory.Create(...);
        DomainEvents.Raise(completedEvent);
    }

}
```

And my resolve was inside of the Raise method:

```
public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
{
    ...

    Container.ResolveAll<IHandle<T>>();   
}
```

I was catching an **InvalidOperationException** - The current type, ...IHandle`1[...IEvent], is **an interface and cannot be constructe**d. Are you missing a type mapping?

Here is the solution :

```
public interface IEventFactory
{
     CompletedEvent Create(...);
}
```

Lessons that I learned:

1. Do not violate fundamental principles, however promising it may seems at the moment.
2. Include the exception in the post as it is a valuable input into the information about the problem.